# Minutes from midnight in Moment.JS on day of Daylight Savings

Tags: javascript, momentjs, dst

I am using the Moment.js library and I am trying to get the number minutes that have passed since midnight for a given timestamp.  It works well, except for on days in which day light savings occurs (etc. March 8th, 2015).

How can i accurately get the number of minutes since midnight for all days of the year? Do I have to get the timezone or offset?

http://jsfiddle.net/0uvz61xo/1/

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var minutesFromMidnight = moment("2015-03-08 03:05:00").diff(moment("2015-03-08").startOf('day'), 'minutes')
    $('#minutes').text(minutesFromMidnight);

});
```

HTML

```
Actual Minutes: <div id="minutes" style="font-weight: bold; color: red;"></div>
<br />
Expected Minutes: <b>185</b> (3 hours and 5 minutes after midnight)
```

Answer (score 2):

The code you gave is indeed the correct way to get the number of elapsed minutes since the start of the day, and the results are correct.  Even though the time on the clock is 3:05, there have actually only been 2 hours and 5 minutes elapsed since midnight, since the hour between 2:00 and 3:00 was skipped.  In the fall, you'd have the opposite effect - that an *extra* hour is added, as the hour between 1:00 and 2:00 is repeated.

It's important to realize that DST is not the same for everyone.  Many countries don't have it at all, and those that do have it don't all do it on the same days or at the same time of day.  For example, Brazil springs forward in October and skips the hour from 00:00 to 01:00.  So on that day *midnight doesn't exist*.   The start of day is 1:00 on that day.  Hopefully that helps you understand why time elapsed since midnight is not necessarily equivalent to the hours and minutes values on the clock.  If midnight doesn't exist the question is invalid, and even if it does exist that doesn't account for possible discontinuities.

That said, if you really need a time-of-day value as a raw number of minutes, it's quite easy to get that:

```
var m = moment("2015-03-08 03:05:00");
var result = m.hour() * 60 + m.minute();
```

Though do keep in mind that this is *not* elapsed time since midnight.

Also recognize that if you have a value like `2015-11-01 01:30:00` in the US, that's during the fall-back transition so there are *two* instances of 1:30.  First comes 1:30 daylight time, then an hour later comes 1:30 standard time.  You can calculate `90` as the result of this time, but that in no way tells you which of the two instances it was.  Again, it's not necessarily 90 minutes since midnight.  It *could* be, or it could be 150 minutes since midnight if it was the second occurrence of 1:30 AM.

See also, [the DST tag wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/dst/info), which has some nice graphs to help you visualize this.